# Are Documentation examples not yet included in the sitewide search?

Tags: support, documentation

I selected some random example from Qt Signals and Slots Documentation topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/qt/2136/signals-and-slots/7932/the-new-qt5-connection-syntax

I tried to find it be using the site search (input field top right at the side). For this purpose I entered the exact name of the example i.e. "The new Qt5 connection syntax" into the search.

I expected searches to considers contents of both, Q&A and Documentation.

Is it desired behavior that the Documentation example isn't listed in the search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation Topics and Examples are not yet integrated into the sitewide search.

Eventually when Documentation graduates from beta they will be consolidated, but for now Documentation has its own search bar.

[image]